# Is there a ODIN or heimdall varient on Xperia?

Tags: rom-flashing, sony-xperia, odin

This one is what it says on the tin is there a form of ODIN and similar clients that have the capability to flash Stock and Custom ROMS to a Not boot loader unlocked device. I prefer if its built in Linux, but I don't mind using wine

Using Sony Xperia E C1505, android 4.1.1
*Small note- if it relies on ro.product.name or the android version to detect a device,  no can do. I will accept universal flashing tools too.*

Answer (score -1):

Yup for Sony experia devices it is called Androxyde Flashtool 
-Flashtool is a software used to flash Sony [Ericsson] Xperia line (2010 to 2013) phones that use the S1 protocol

Please check http://www.flashtool.net to have more informations

Comment: Avoid 1 line answers. Please provide some information about the things you mention. Also give website links.

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to this forum

Comment: @jandeboer errr it does not seem to be compatible with my particular device,  can you provide a download link to a version that applies to me?

Comment: http://xperiafirmware.com/8-firmware/35-sony-xperia-e-c1505